# Flex: How can I pop up a component in the center of the user's viewable area?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, popup

Let's assume I have an application whose dimensions are larger than the user's screen resolution. Typically, when adding a popup I would call `popupManager.addPopup()` followed by `popupManager.centerPopup()`, but this could cause the popup to be added outside of the user's visible area on screen.

Is there a way to add a popup in the middle of the user's *current* viewable area instead?

**EDIT:**
Here's a quick example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               width="3000" height="2000" 
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

      import mx.managers.PopUpManager;          
      import spark.components.TitleWindow;

      public var myWindow:TitleWindow = new TitleWindow;

      protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
      {
        myWindow.title = "My Title Window";
        PopUpManager.addPopUp(myWindow, DisplayObject(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication), false);
        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(myWindow);
      }

    ]]>
  </fx:Script>

  <s:BorderContainer width="3000" height="2000" backgroundColor="0x000000" />
</s:Application>
```

**Example 1:**

```
+==========================+---------------------+
|      Viewable Area       |                     |
|                          |                     |
|     +-------------+      |                     |
|     |  I want the |      |                     |
|     |   popup to  |      |                     |
|     |   go here.  |      |                     |
|     +-------------+      |                     |
|                          |                     |
|                          |                     |
+==========================+                     |
|                                                |
|                Rest of Application             |
|                                                |
|                                                |
|                                                |
|                                                |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

**Example 2:**

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                                |
|                Rest of Application             |
|                                                |
|                                                |
|                +===========================+   |
|                |       Viewable Area       |   |
|                |                           |   |
|                |      +-------------+      |   |
|                |      |  I want the |      |   |
|                |      |   popup to  |      |   |
|                |      |   go here.  |      |   |
|                |      +-------------+      |   |
|                |                           |   |
|                |                           |   |
|                +===========================+   |
|                                                |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I would have expected that centerPopUp centered the component in the apps visible area. Since you said "could cause" not "does cause" Do you have code proving that this is not the case, or are you just trying to prepare for what you think may happen? You want to center the item relative to local coordinates of the Application tag but you're saying it is centering based on the content coordinates.  Are you sure that's correct? http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_5.html

Comment: @Flextras, I added a quick code snippit to demonstrate the issue I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it by hand using the stageWidth and stageHeight properties of the stage property:

```
dlg.x = (this.stage.stageWidth / 2) - (dlg.width / 2);
dlg.y = (this.stage.stageHeight / 2) - (dlg.height / 2);
```

There may be a more "correct" way to get the dimensions of the viewable area, but I've found that this gets the job done.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Fixed my mis-information :)

Comment: @Wade Mueller, I can't seem to find the `width` and `height` properties for `systemManager`. Do those properties exist in Flex 4?

Comment: @Jason, sorry about that, not sure what I was thinking of.  Edited my answer to something that makes more sense :)

Comment: @Wade Mueller, Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately, the popup window still pops up off screen after calling `myTitleWindow.move(_x,_y);` where `_x` and `_y` are `(this.stage.stageWidth / 2) - (dlg.width / 2)` and `(this.stage.stageHeight / 2) - (dlg.height / 2)` respectively. Am I not implementing it correctly?

Comment: Hmm, that looks correct to me.  If I were you I would start by either setting breakpoints and stepping through the calculations, or use trace statements to see the before/after values for you window's x and y values.

Comment: @Wade Mueller, Here are the trace results using the same example I posted above:  `BEFORE MOVING: myWindow.x = 0, myWindow.y = 0
AFTER MOVING: myWindow.x = 1430, myWindow.y = 962`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jason Try to call validateNow on your popup before calculating its position, as its height and width might return 0 until then. Also you might want to use explicitOrMeasuredWidth instead of width, and the coresponding one for height.

Comment: @bug-a-lot, The `x` and `y` coords are 0, 0 at first because I just added the popup without centering it so it was added at those coords by default. I tried calling `validateNow()` after adding the popup and before moving it. I also used `explicitHeight` and `explicitWidth` as you recommended. Here are the trace results: `BEFORE MOVING: myWindow.x = 0 myWindow.y = 0
AFTER MOVING: myWindow.x = 0 myWindow.y = 0`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I suspect bug-a-lot is right in that the size of the just-created window is not calculated yet and is coming back as 0.  You could set the position after the size is known by using callLater.

Comment: @Wade Mueller, Is knowing the popup's size preventing me from showing it in the user's visible area? It looks like the first trace I posted after you updated your answer calculated the x and y coords after measuring the TitleWindow correctly. The problem was it still popped up outside of the user's visible area. See the mock ups I posted above on where the popup should show up in each scenario for reference. I guess another way of asking the question is how can I get the x and y coords of the user's currently visible area of a component?

Comment: Oh I get it now.  You want to know what the BROWSER scroll position and viewable area dimensions are.  The only way that I am aware of to get that info is to call out to the browser using javascript.  Sorry if I sent you down the wrong path.

Comment: @Wade Mueller, No worries. If you come across any examples that might help out, let me know. :)

Comment: Accepted Wade's answer since this is the path I'll most likely have to take.

Answer (score 2):

`centerPopUp()` uses the `parent` object that is passed to `addPopUp()` or `createPopUp()` as reference for centering the pop-up. If `parent` is the application, then it should already be centered based on the `width` and `height` of the application - which is what the "viewable area" is from Flex's point of view.

So try passing the application object as the `parent` argument to `addPopUp()` or `createPopUp()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added a quick code snippit that demonstrates the issue I'm referring to. Hopefully that helps explain things a bit better. :)

Comment: PopUpManager.createPopUp(parentApplication as DisplayObject, ..., ...)  may solve the center issue.